# Cancelling a delayed task before it has completed

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, task, token

I am creating a list of tasks that are to be completed at different times of the day.  For each task I create, I associate it with a CancellationTokenSource. However, calling `PoolOfTasks(0).Token.Cancel()` seems to just make the task execute instantly instead of not at all. I wish to completely abort the task from running.

If the task is not cancelled, it should execute after the specified delay of 10 seconds.

Here's the code I've cooked up so far - I'm confused as to why the method is still invoked (and why it is invoked without a delay) when I cancel the CancellationToken. I have probably misunderstood the concept of them.

```
Module Module1
Public Structure TaskCheckout

    Public Token As CancellationTokenSource
    Public Task As Task
    Public TimeToCheckout As TimeSpan

End Structure

Private PoolOfTasks As New ObservableCollection(Of TaskCheckout)

Sub Main()


    Dim Checkout As New TaskCheckout
    With Checkout
        .Token = New CancellationTokenSource
        .TimeToCheckout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
        .Task = Task.Delay(Checkout.TimeToCheckout, .Token.Token).ContinueWith(AddressOf methodToCall)
    End With

    PoolOfTasks.Add(Checkout)

    Task.Delay(500)

    PoolOfTasks(0).Token.Cancel()


    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub

Private Sub methodToCall()

    MsgBox("Hey!")

End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: @Nkosi The `.ContinueWith(AddressOf methodToCall)` will auto-invoke the method after the task has completed the delay. That's where the task is executed, right?

Comment: Oh, that would explain the instant method invoke when the token is cancalled right? Because that would "complete" the delay. Any suggestion as to how I can delay the task, and completely avoid it from invoking the method when cancelled/aborted?

Comment: @Nkosi Nope. ;-) Turns out I just had to add a cancellation token to the .ContinueWith aswell - then it doesn't invoke if cancelled. As in `.Task = Task.Delay(Checkout.TimeToCheckout, .Token.Token).ContinueWith(Sub(x) methodToCall(), .Token.Token)`

Comment: Ok then. great. glad you got it working. Add it as a self answer and hopefully it helps others with a similar issue. I'll remove previous comments to clean up the comments